# Rotate Windows XP Desktop

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, monitor

My LCD rotates.  The software that comes with my ATI card to rotate the desktop just crashes (*I've uninstalled, reinstalled and rolled them back, still crashes*).  Is there any other way to rotate a Windows XP Desktop by 90 degree increments?  I am looking for either software or code (any language is fine.)  I know I have seen 3rd party support for this before, but I can't find it now.

I realize this may not be a strictly software development related question, but it is programmer productivity related.  If I can get an answer that involves how to write a program to do this, even better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IRotate: http://www.entechtaiwan.net/util/irotate.shtm.
Have not used it but heard good things.

Same people that make Powerstrip http://www.entechtaiwan.net/util/ps.shtm.
Which gets rave reviews from the HTPC crowd.

Was looking at these recently while researching stuff for an HTPC.
Both are try before buy shareware.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to give you the answer you probably already know, but yeah this is a video card driver software thing and if the ATI software crashes then it's either corrupted or buggy or your Windows install has gone rotten.

I've done this before on my NVidia-based cards without issue. I've never owned an ATI card.

Answer (score 0):

[iRotate](http://www.entechtaiwan.net/util/irotate.shtm) worked great, and it is free for personal use.  Very quick and painless install.  Thanks [seanb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3354/).  My only complaint is it binds hot keys to CTRL+ALT+[arrows], so I have to close it after I rotate.  It seems to stay rotated, but I guess I will see what happens when I reboot.

Answer (score 0):

XP with SP3 has a known issue with ATI video cards where it will not rotate the desktop.

I'm thinking I might go back to SP2 to get that back.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on Desktop
-> Graphics Properties...
-> Display Settings
-> Enable Rotation
-> 90 degrees
Well, it works on my laptop (XP Professional, SP3).

Comment: That is a special feature of your video card drivers that adds that tab.